# Ruby gems not listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed ruby gems using

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

after that, when I type

```
gem -v
```

the answer is **1.8.15**, when I type

```
which gem
```

the answer is **/usr/bin/gem**
 ,but when I type

```
gem list
```

it shows *** LOCAL GEMS ***, 
not the list of gems, whats the problem?

Comment: Do you installed any gem packages?

Comment: No, I have done only what is written in question

Comment: You can try to install some gem packages, for example: "gem install rake", then run "gem list".

Comment: Is there a way to download most common gem packages in one command?

Comment: `gem install rails` would do that... but I'm more worried about which version of ruby you're using, and the fact that you seem to think `sudo` is a good way to use it. See my answer.

Comment: Depending on your requirements， If you want to develop a rails app, suggest you install rails, rake and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer, but the apt-get ruby packages have always been flawed and cause issues like yours. Use [RVM](http://rvm.io/) instead.

If `gem list` shows only the message "* LOCAL GEMS *" then there are no local gems found. That means either there are no gems installed, or your GEM_PATH is messed up (due to apt-get not working right).

Comment: ok, is there a way to remove the work that apt-get did?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Comment: And one more warning: don't install RVM using `apt-get`! Use instructions on the [official RVM website](http://rvm.io/) so that RVM is installed in user space.